# How do I keep the focus on an input, after i click on a button without flickering in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, focus, vuejs3

**Script**

```js
const amountRef = ref(null);
const amount = ref(0.1);

const insertSuggestion = (e, value) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  amount.value = value;
  amountRef.value.focus();
};
```

**Template**

```html
<Suggestion
   class="..."
   v-for="suggestion in suggestions"
   :key="suggestion"
   @click="insertSuggestion($event, suggestion)"
>
    {{ suggestion }}
</Suggestion>
<input
   class="..."
   @keyup.enter="handleBuy"
   placeholder="Amount"
   ref="amountRef"
   v-model="amount"
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-focus the input element on the `blur` event:

```html
<input ref="amountRef" @blur="$refs.amountRef.focus()"/>
```

**Edit**

You also need to check the `relatedTarget` of the `blur` event to make sure you only re-focus when one of the buttons is clicked.

Note: this solution does not work on Firefox.

```html
<Suggestion
   class="suggestion-btn"
   ...
>
</Suggestion>
<input
   ref="amountRef"
   @blur="onBlur"
/>
```

```js
onBlur(evt) {
    if (
        evt.relatedTarget &&
        evt.relatedTarget.classList.contains("suggestion-btn")
    ) {
        this.$refs.amountRef.focus();
    }
},
```

Comment: Not the nicest solution but at least it works and is simple! Sufficient enough for my particular case.

Comment: Seems sensitive to browser implementation. I don't know why it is behaving like that in Firefox. Also, this solution re-focuses every time, no matter if you click on one of the buttons or not.

Answer (score 2):

### **Stop the de-focusing with @pointerdown.prevent**

**TLDR:** `pointerdown` (or `mousedown`) occurs before `blur` (or `click`), so use it to prevent subsequent default events that occur when the click or tap is finished.

**NOTE:** I believe you can use `pointerdown` or `mousedown` events interchangeably.

I strongly advise avoiding *any* focus change at all, even if it's a re-focus, as any state change may invoke a cascade of secondary state changes especially if used with some deeply nested components. Even if it works, at the least you risk a visual "hiccup" exposed to the user (yuck).

Instead, you should try to actually stop the de-focusing from happening in the first place.

You had the right idea with `@click` and a subsequent `e.preventDefault()`, but a click event occurs *after* blurring.

Instead, make the `preventDefault` occur *before* blur occurs, by triggering it from an earlier event, `pointerdown`, which occurs before blur & click.

Simply add Vue's `@pointerdown.prevent` on elements where, when clicked, you don't want another element (on the page) to de-focus. With this, the OP can get rid of a bunch of lines:

**Script**

```
const insertSuggestion = (value) => {
  // NOT NEEDED ANYMORE:
  // e.preventDefault();
  // e.stopPropagation();
  // amountRef.value.focus();

  // KEEP:
  amount.value = value
}
```

**Template**

```
<Suggestion
   class="..."
   v-for="suggestion in suggestions"
   :key="suggestion"
   @pointerdown.prevent
   @click="insertSuggestion(suggestion)"
>
    {{ suggestion }}
</Suggestion>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to capture the blur event and add the classes back if the `relatedTarget` is one of those buttons. Super psuedo code below:

```
<input
   class="..."
   @keyup.enter="handleBuy"
   @blur="maybeMimicFocus"
   placeholder="Amount"
   ref="amountRef"
   v-model="amount"
/>
```

```
maybeMimicFocus (event) {
  if (event.relatedTarget && event.relatedTarget.tagname === 'btn') {
    this.$refs.amountRef.$el.classList.add('the-classes-that-make-it-look-focused')
  }
}
```

the browser won't have to repaint the dom and therefore this transaction should be so quick that the naked eye won't see it a difference. the only caveat I can see is if there are animations attached to transitioning properties in which those will have to fire.

Comment: This is a very "hacky" solution, which is nothing new in the javascript world. But the real problem comes, when it's not simple nor reusable. It depends on a particular class to work, which is different in each case.