# I want button onClick() function to be executed first before textarea onBlur function() in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, dom, dom-events

I have a textarea with `onBlur()` function, and also a button with `onClick()` function,

The button will be visible only if the textarea is focussed, and when clicked on the button I want to display some text.

The problem is the textarea `onBlur()` function is executed before the button `onClick()` function.

How can I prevent this from happening? If you could please help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Please refer [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-fast-lqqoy3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: you want to show the text and then hide the button next when the button is clicked ?

Comment: This is not a good design.. Anyway to click on something you need to focus on it so obviously it'll blur the first element.. I believe you'll need to rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I keep the focus on an input, after i click on a button without flickering in Vue 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501700/how-do-i-keep-the-focus-on-an-input-after-i-click-on-a-button-without-flickerin)

Comment: @KcH Yes, the button should be visible only when the textarea is focussed. The button or text that I am displaying on button click will not be visible if the textarea is not focussed. And I want to display the text only on button click.

Comment: @VedantTerkar You are absolutely right, but I want to execute the button onClick() function before the textarea onBlur() function triggers. I want onBlur() to be executed but after onClick().

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that the onBlur is a default behaviour of the textarea. It will be triggered as soon as you click anywhere outside the textarea.

So, to achieve the desired behaviour, change the state on button click rather than on onBlur.
I have attached the snippet below, Hope this will help.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [editorFocus, setEditorFocus] = useState(false);
  const [textVisibility, setTextVisibility] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <textarea
        onFocus={() => {
          setEditorFocus(true);
          setTextVisibility(false);
        }}
        // onBlur={() => setEditorFocus(false)}
      ></textarea>
      {editorFocus && (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setTextVisibility(true);
            setEditorFocus(false);
          }}
        >
          Click me!
        </button>
      )}
      {textVisibility && <h1>Hello World!</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-smoke-96qj08?file=/src/App.js:0-709)

Comment: Ok then the button will disappear if and only if the user clicks on the button rather than clicking anywhere

Comment: Yes @Molly I want the button to be disabled if the text area is not focussed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an event listener that checks the active item every time the user clicks. If the tagName of the active element is BUTTON or TEXTAREA the editorFocus can be set to true, if not than set the editorFocus to false.

Hope this helps!

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [editorFocus, setEditorFocus] = useState(false);
  const [textVisibility, setTextVisibility] = useState(false);

  const clickCheck = (e) => {
    // checks to see if the active element has a tagName of "button or textarea"
    if (
      document.activeElement.tagName === "BUTTON" ||
      document.activeElement.tagName === "TEXTAREA"
    ) {
      setEditorFocus(true);
    } else {
      setEditorFocus(false);
    }
  };

  // Adds event listener that calls the clickCheck function every time the user clicks
  document.addEventListener("click", () => clickCheck());

  return (
    <div className="App" id="div">
      <div>
        <textarea></textarea>
        {editorFocus && (
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setTextVisibility(true);
            }}
          >
            Click me!
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
      {textVisibility && <h1>Hello World!</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-resonance-7suj8e?file=/src/App.js)